# Update date format in spark dataframe for multiple spark columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, simpledateformat

I have a Spark dataframe where few columns having a different type of date format.
To handle this I have written below code to keep a consistent type of format for all the date columns.
As the date column date format may get change every time hence I have defined a set of date formats in `dt_formats`.

```
def to_timestamp_multiple(s: Column, formats: Seq[String]): Column = {
    coalesce(formats.map(fmt => to_timestamp(s, fmt)):_*)
}

val dt_formats= Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","MM/dd/yy","dd-MM-yy","dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy")

val newDF =  df.withColumn("ETD1", date_format(to_timestamp_multiple($"ETD",Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy", dt_formats)).cast("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).drop("ETD").withColumnRenamed("ETD1","ETD")
```

But here I have to create a new column then I have to drop older column then rename the new column.
that make the code unnecessary very clumsy hence I want to get override from this code.

I am trying to implement similar functionality by writing a Scala below function but it is throwing the exception `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:`, but I am unable to identify the what change I should made to make it work..

```
val CleansedData= rawDF.selectExpr(rawDF.columns.map( 
x => { x match {
  case "ETA" => s"""date_format(to_timestamp_multiple($x, dt_formats).cast("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd") as ETA"""
  case _ => x
}  }   ) : _*)
```

Hence seeking help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html) in order to use with `select`. [The select method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#select(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) takes columns and produces another DataFrame.

Also, instead of using `coalesce`, it might be more straightforward simply to build a parser that handles all of the formats. You can use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) for this.

```scala
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import java.time.LocalDate
import scala.util.Try
import java.sql.Date

val dtFormatStrings:Seq[String] = Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","MM/dd/yy","dd-MM-yy","dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy")

// use foldLeft with appendOptional method, which for each format,
// returns a new builder with that additional possible format

val initBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
val builder: DateTimeFormatterBuilder = dtFormatStrings.foldLeft(initBuilder)(
  (b: DateTimeFormatterBuilder, s:String) => b.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(s)))
val formatter = builder.toFormatter()

// Create the UDF, which just takes
// any function returning a sql-compatible type (java.sql.Date, here)

def toTimeStamp2(dateString:String): Date = {
  val dateTry: Try[Date] = Try(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter)))
  dateTry.toOption.getOrElse(null)
}

val timeConversionUdf = udf(toTimeStamp2 _)

// example DF and new DF
val df = Seq(("05/08/20"), ("2020-04-03"), ("unparseable")).toDF("ETD")
df.select(timeConversionUdf(col("ETD"))).toDF("ETD2").show
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|      ETD2|
+----------+
|2020-05-08|
|2020-04-03|
|      null|
+----------+
```

Note that unparseable values end up null, as shown.

Comment: I am getting the below exception- `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

Comment: Try moving any non-serializable items into static classes (i.e. a Scala object) or instantiating them inside the UDF/on the executor.

Answer (score 0):

try `withColumn(...)` with same name and coalesce as below-

```scala
val dt_formats= Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","MM/dd/yy","dd-MM-yy","dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy/MM/dd","dd/MM/yyyy")

val newDF =  df.withColumn("ETD", coalesce(dt_formats.map(fmt => to_date($"ETD", fmt)):_*))
```

Comment: but this will add new column and again and have to perform drop and rename column :(

Comment: no, this won't add new column, have you tried? Doc says **withColumn - Returns a new Dataset by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.**

Comment: I just saw the `withcolumn` hence didn't tried.. but definitely will try to implement.

Comment: can you pls help me on this qus- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521079/self-join-in-spark-and-apply-multiple-filter-criteria-in-spark-scala/62521586?noredirect=1#comment110568564_62521586

Comment: @BlueStar, is this solution working for you? please let me know, if you face any problems